# How to recompile a Python toolbox after a change to an imported module

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, python-toolbox

If an ArcPy toolbox imports modules that are edited, recompiling the modules from the .py source code to the .pyc code that actually runs is a challenge. Deleting the .pyc files doesn't work because (this is a guess) ArcMap keeps a copy of the files in memory. Only a saved change to the main .pyt file triggers a full refresh of the code and it isn't clear that this is a reliable way to recompile.

My current working fix for this is below in case it's useful. Do you have any additional suggestions for how to handle this part of the toolbox creation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files are structures as below use `reload(module)` to recompile each time you refresh the toolbox in ArcMap.

main.pyt:

```
import arcpy
import tool_file
reload(tool_file)
from tool_file import test_tool

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "ToolboxLabel"
        self.alias = "tool_box_alias"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [test_tool]
```

tool_file.py:

```
import arcpy


class test_tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "test_tool"
        self.description = "tool to test"
        self.canRunInBackground = False


    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        params = None


        return params


    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True


    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.    This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed. in the window interface"""

        return


    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.    This method is called after internal validation."""

        # *************************************************************************
        # change this message to test whether changes are being reflected correctly 
        # when you refresh in arcmap
        arcpy.AddMessage('hello world')
        # *************************************************************************
        return


    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        return
```